# How to prevent Outlook from sending emails with my personal account?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

My company uses Office365 and we use Outlook for email communications. I also added my personal email account <sup>(I'm using Gmail if it matters)</sup> to Outlook. Is there any way to totally disable sending mails from my personal account so I can avoid using personal account to send work emails?

Comment: Company equipment is for company e-mail. You shouldn't be adding your personal Gmail account to your company-issued equipment. Use the GMail web app instead.

Comment: Outlook should not do this in the first place. When you configure emailboxes as primary accounts in outlook, Outlook should reply with the same email account as the email was sent to. As for sending new emails, outlook will use the email account that you currently have selected. If you make it a habit to always switch back to your office email account, you should not run into accidentally sending out an email from a personal account.

Comment: @LPChip  humans make mistakes. :)

Comment: What I see happening is people use their own personal devices (smartphones normally) for personal email and keep the two things very separate. LPChip's solution works if you insist on having your personal mail on a company machine.

Comment: Just remember, in the US, if you put private emails on company equipment, courts have ruled that the employer has rights to look at and even copy your 'personal' emails. That's why using a separate, personal, device is preferable. Just FYI.

Comment: This question is still relevant despite the employer/employee concerns.  I am a consultant/contractor who is often given an email account for my clients. If I have myname@companyA.com and myname@companyB.com, I would really like for the companyA.com account to be prevented from sending to the companyB.com domain.  This is especially important with meeting invites where there is not a clear way to see which account is being used unless you select "edit response before sending",

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to block sending out emails from your main account, you can do the following.

In outlook, go to File, then select your gmail account.
Now go to Account settings -> Server settings.

Unvold the Outgoing email section and change the server to something like: dontuse.

Hit next to apply the changes. Gmail will attempt to verify and will fail. Not entirely sure if you have to type your password in, but I did do that in my test.
Cancel out of the dialog. The changes have been saved regardless.

When you now send an email, the email will be kept in the outbox and not send.
In addition, the statusbar will indicate that there was a send/receive error.

Its can be hard to miss, but at least you have a protection against sending emails out.

Comment: sigh. i thought the settings should be in [Account Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDCfA.png). did not notice there's a "Server settings".

Comment: Microsoft added server settings in outlook 2016 I think, and is only there when using IMAP or POP. If using Exchange, its not there.